# Free product of surface groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Let $$S_g = \langle a_1,b_1,...,a_g,b_g \mid \prod_{i=1}^g[a_i,b_i] = 1 \rangle$$ be the fundamental group of a genus $g$ orientable surface.  Why is $S_g \ast S_h \cong S_{g+h}$, and is there a nice canonical isomorphism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those groups are not isomorphic, for example the free product has infinitely many ends and the surface group has one end since it is [quasi-isometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry) to the hyperbolic plane (surface groups act geometrically on the hyperbolic plane you can apply [Svarc-Milnor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C5%A0varc%E2%80%93Milnor_lemma)) which is one ended. You might be interested in [Stallings theorem on ends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stallings_theorem_about_ends_of_groups).

Comment: Thanks - sorry I miss understood something - thanks for the help!

Comment: @user101010 Not a problem, it is a somewhat cute problem to prove false, and to see some applications of basic geometric group theory.

Comment: Nice answer! Here's a perhaps more topological way to do it, however: surfaces are $K(G, 1)$-spaces, so an isomorphism $S_g * S_h \cong S_{g+h}$ gives a homotopy equivalence $\Sigma_g \vee \Sigma_h \cong \Sigma_{g+h}$, where $\Sigma_\bullet$ denotes a surface of appropriate genus. But the 2nd homology groups don't agree. In short, the 2nd group (co)homology of the two groups don't agree.